# CPU fan kicks in to full gear when i try to install ubuntu 12.10 or LTS

Tags: ati, system-installation, cpu, fan

Whenever I try to install (DUAL BOOT WITH WINDOWS 7) both versions of Ubuntu desktop on my PC the CPU fan starts spinning so fast that I couldn't even go through the installation for fear of my CPU exploding.

In windows 7, the temp reaches 25-30 idle and 30-45 under full load. I tried installing through Wubi and by burning it to USB drive. Both wield the same results.

I would appreciate any help. I'm a complete noob so take it easy one me.

- Intel Core i5 2500 @ 3.30GHz
- 4.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 668MHz (9-9-9-24)
- Motherboard ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8Z68-V LX (LGA1155)
- Graphics AMD Radeon HD 6850 (Sapphire/PCPartner)

Comment: Try with `nomodeset` for that graphics card: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: This is my case http://askubuntu.com/questions/706737/abnormal-fan-behavior-sticking-and-persist-on-max-speed-hp-envy-6-1154er-ubu. I don't know how to fix this. I tried different suggestions. I installed Laptop Mode Tools which made things better, but anyway the issue still exists