# Abnormal fan behavior: Sticking and persist on max speed (HP Envy 6-1154er & Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, hp, cpu, fan

### 1.

I have HP Envy 6-1154er under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I encountered the invalid fan behavior. As cpu load grows and if it makes fan to work on max speed the speed never goes back to "silent mode". When I login after power up it's quiet. But it's enough to start e.g. Google Chrome with several tabs opened I get the fan start rotating on max RPM. Then after cpu goes to idle the fan anyway operates on high speed. Only restart resets this.

I tried this.

`$ sudo sensors-detect` gives me this

```
...
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
(driver `coretemp')
...
```

and suggestes those modules *i2c-dev, i2c-i801, cpuid*.
I loaded them via `modprobe` and tried

`$ sensors` output

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +66.0°C  (crit = +106.0°C)
temp2:        +66.0°C  (crit = +106.0°C)
temp3:        +27.8°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +59.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

`$ sudo pwmconfig` result is

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

So I can't use `fancontrol` farther.

### 2.

Then I found this topic [Persistent High-Fan Speed Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04/537538#537538) I did what is suggested and fan started working slightly better.

> Fan speed is normalized by editing the line
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> in the grub configuration file found at /etc/default/grub so that it
>   reads
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"

### 3.

After I installed [utils](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) proposed here 
[Abnormally High Fan Speed on Cool Laptop, Dell Inspiron 15R 5520, Ubuntu 14.04,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506440/abnormally-high-fan-speed-on-cool-laptop-dell-inspiron-15r-5520-ubuntu-14-04)

The fan started working significantly better. It doesn't become noisy up to  about 15% cpu load, but anyway If I open something "heavy" and cpu load increases essentially that makes fan to go to max speed it also doesn't go back to low speed even when the temperature is low and cpu load is about 2-5%. And now if I do suspend and wake the laptop up the speed normalizes.

The issue exists from the beginning (installation).
On Windows I had no this issue, but I don't want get Windows back, I liked Linux.

---

- [Laptop fan speed abnormally high after installing 13.04, Unity doesn't load after installing and removing fglrx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294012/laptop-fan-speed-abnormally-high-after-installing-13-04-unity-doesnt-load-afte)
- [Abnormally High Fan Speed on Cool Laptop, Dell Inspiron 15R 5520, Ubuntu 14.04,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506440/abnormally-high-fan-speed-on-cool-laptop-dell-inspiron-15r-5520-ubuntu-14-04)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same with my HP Pavillion 15 under Lubuntu 15.10. Under Windows 8.1 the fan rarely made any noise when using Chrome and JavaScript-heavy games.

`+++ System Info
System         = Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC
BIOS           = F.06
Release        = Ubuntu 15.10
Kernel         = 4.2.0-19-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 11 11:39:30 UTC 2015 x86_64
Init system    = systemd

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = AC`

Comment: Eventually, I found the solution that made things better.

    $sudo tlp bat 

did the trick. And for persistent modify `/etc/default/tlp`, set the default mode to battery.

    TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT

Now I have gently working fan if the temperature doesn't exceed the high limit in 87°C. But if it does the fan stick on it's speed and doesn't get low when temperature is already low. I also noticed that there is no changes in performance.

Comment: Ok it's a workaround, I'll try it out and see how it works for the next couple of days.

Comment: I don't know how this works. Today it may work for a while, but tomorrow you get the incredibly spinning fan. I upgraded to 16.04 then to 4.6 kernel. It seems it made things better, but anyway issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the solution was switching to [Manjaro KDE](https://manjaro.org). All the issues not only fan related I had with Ubuntu disappeared. Manjaro runs perfectly.